# Magento 2 Blank Admin Page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, installation

I was able to install Magento 2 on "Windows environment" using "WAMP".

After successful installation, when I'm trying to access admin panel, I'm seeing a blank page with a white popup as follows.

[image]

I've enabled `mod_rewrite` on apache and set `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 400` as well.

On `system.log` seeing the below message.

```
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'global_notices' element cannot be added as child to 'global.notices', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'logo' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'global.search' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'user' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'menu' element cannot be added as child to 'page.menu', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'breadcrumbs' element cannot be added as child to 'page.breadcrumbs', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'formkey' element cannot be added as child to 'page.formkey', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.title' element cannot be added as child to 'main.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'messages' element cannot be added as child to 'page.messages', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.actions.toolbar' element cannot be added as child to 'page.main.actions', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'locale.switcher' element cannot be added as child to 'footer', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'legal' element cannot be added as child to 'footer', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.loader' element cannot be added as child to 'backend.page', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'system_messages' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'unread_system_messages' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'notification_window' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.left' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.right' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'logo' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'global.search' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'user' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.actions.toolbar' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'page.main.actions' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.loader' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'backend.page' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'system_messages' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'notifications' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'unread_system_messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'system_messages', but their parents are different: 'notifications' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.left' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.right' tries to reorder itself towards 'header.inner.left', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'global.search' tries to reorder itself towards 'notification.messages', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and '' respectively. [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:\www\magento2-1\app\code\Magento\Backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:\www\magento2-1\app\code\Magento\Translation/view/base/templates/translate.phtml' [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:\www\magento2-1\app\code\Magento\Backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/components.phtml' [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:\www\magento2-1\app\code\Magento\Backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/calendar.phtml' [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:\www\magento2-1\app\code\Magento\Ui/view/base/templates/logger.phtml' [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:\www\magento2-1\app\code\Magento\Backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/header.phtml' [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:\www\magento2-1\app\code\Magento\Backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml' [] []
[2015-10-13 07:43:51] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'D:\www\magento2-1\app\code\Magento\Backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/copyright.phtml' [] []
```

Did I miss something on installation?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed the grunt CLI? Because magento generates static files like, css, js, images and uses them, may be this is the issue. You should run  grunt task for backend after installing the grunt CLI (If you have not done it already).

Comment: @Taral: No I haven't install Grunt CLI. Can you please explain how to run grunt task for back-end?

Comment: @osan: Ok, i will explain it as an answer as it will be more convenient to explain

Comment: How to fix the blank page bug (October 2015): https://mage2.pro/t/132  
Here is the problem description on GitHub: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2077#issuecomment-147187281

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's know issue. Fix will be available in one of next updates.

Problem in path registration  ComponentRegistrar.php class. 
$path on windows comes with other slashes,  they are not normalized and a lot of methods doesn't pass check, for example here:
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator::isValid

To fix, please replace `self::$paths[$type][$componentName] = $path;` on 51 line to 
`self::$paths[$type][$componentName] = str_replace('\\', '/', $path);`

Answer (score 0):

1: Install node.js to any location on your machine.
2: Open terminal/command prompt.
3: Run this command `npm install -g grunt-cli`.
4:Run this`cd <your_Magento_instance_directory>` and then this commands
  `npm install grunt --save-dev`
5:Run this command `npm install` And `npm update`.
6: After all the dependencies are installed, you can Run this command `grunt less:backend`
This will generate static files for the adminhtml.
7: Also you can run `grunt exec:backend` to generate admin theme files if there is a problem in them.

Thank you.